# How to add dropdown options to multi row form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have made a form that users can click to add news rows.

```html
<?php
include('session.php');
?>

<?php 
$ItemID = "ItemID";
$ItemName = "ItemName";
$UnitPrice = "UnitPrice";

$sql = "SELECT ItemID,ItemName,UnitPrice FROM Item";
$result = $db->query($sql);
?> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Sales</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Add new Sales Record</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="sales.php"><button  class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Back</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container" align="right">
    <table class="table-sm">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-primar">
                <th scope="col" style="padding-right: 50px;">ItemID</th>
                <th scope="col" style="padding-right: 50px">ItemName</th>
                <th scope="col">UnitPrice</th>
            </tr>
        
            <?php 
            while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                ?>
                <tr class="contents">
                    <td><?php echo $rows[$ItemID]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows[$ItemName]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows[$UnitPrice]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php   
            } 
            ?> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th class="text-center">
                                ItemID
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                Amount
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <form action="addsales.php" method="POST">
                            <tr id='addr0'>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='itemid' placeholder='ItemID' class="form-control"/>
                                </select>
                                </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name='amount' placeholder='Amount' class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                    </form>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
        <button id="add_row" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" style="position: absolute; right: 130px;">New row</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Save</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 1;
      $("#add_row").click(function() {
        $('#addr'+(i-1)).find('input').attr('disabled',true);

        $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='itemid" + i + "'  placeholder='ItemID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='amount" + i + "' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is to change the itemid field to a drop down list that comes from a database query. I have managed to do it for the first row field. But, the problem I encoutered later is that I do not know how to make the list appear again on the new rows that I inserted using javascript. I have tried to somhow display the list using javascript but it did not work. Unfortunately I have deleted those code and are left with the snippet that I included.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the data in your database changes inbetween queries I'd attach an `eventlistener` to your newly created dropdown. It should trigger an `XHR` call to a PHP-endpoint which performs the query and returns your results in `JSON`. You then iterate over the JSON-response and append it the `input` where each entry is a `select`. 

If your data doesn't change inbetween queries it'd suffice to do one XHR-call on the start of your JS and keep that list as a variable. Then just iterate over that variable whenever needed.

Comment: Thank you for your resonse. I am still a beginer at php and sql. So.. I have no idea what you are talking about... What is XHR???

Comment: XHR or `XHRrequest` is a way of getting data from a webserver to your client without them needing to refresh your page. You may often see websites with spinners which ten suddenly show data. That 'sudden' is made possible with XHR requests. You can see them in your browser console under the network-tab if you want to see how they work. It's also a good idea to work with promisses if you plan on using these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Nesting a `form` between `tbody` and `tr` is illegal in HTML to begin with. With the browser error correction, that can lead to a different DOM than you would expect, and therefor to further problems. This is the first thing you should fix here. The form either needs to go around the whole table, or it needs to be contained in a single table cell.