# Error inserting multi row values with a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have been facing a problem that I have been looking everywhere for a soultion.
I want to make a page where you can insert new rows to a form table, then use these values to insert into database.
Here is an image of how the page I want to make will look like. [sales form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYcvn.png)

The idea behind the page is that one receipt id will be generated and inside there can be many items that users can add, hence the multiple rows.
Here is the code for the form page.

```html
<?php
include('session.php');
?>

<?php 
$ItemID = "ItemID";
$ItemName = "ItemName";
$UnitPrice = "UnitPrice";

$sql = "SELECT ItemID,ItemName,UnitPrice FROM Item";
$result = $db->query($sql);
?> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Sales</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Add new Sales Record</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="sales.php"><button  class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Back</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container" align="right">
        <table class="table-sm">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-primar">
                    <th scope="col" style="padding-right: 50px;">ItemID</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="padding-right: 50px">ItemName</th>
                    <th scope="col">UnitPrice</th>
                </tr>

                <?php 
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                    ?>
                    <tr class="contents">
                        <td><?php echo $rows[$ItemID]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows[$ItemName]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows[$UnitPrice]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php   
                } 
                ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th class="text-center">
                                ItemID
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                Amount
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                Price Sold
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                Branch ID
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                EmployeeID
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                MemberID
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <form action="addsales.php" method="post">
                            <tr id='addr0'>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[][itemid]' placeholder='ItemID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[][amount]' placeholder='Amount' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[][pricesold]' placeholder='PriceSold' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[][branchid]' placeholder='BranchID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[][employeeid]' placeholder='EmployeeID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[][memberid]' placeholder='MemberID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                            <input class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit"/>
                        </form>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="add_row" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" style="position: absolute; right: 130px;">New row</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var i = 1;
          $("#add_row").click(function() {
            $('#addr'+(i-1)).find('input').attr('disabled',true);

            $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='item[][itemid]'  placeholder='ItemID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item[][amount]' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item[][pricesold]' placeholder='PriceSold' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item[][branchid]' placeholder='BranchID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item[][employeeid]' placeholder='EmployeeID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item[][memberid]' placeholder='MemberID' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
            i++;
        });
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The values will be handled in another php page.

```html
<?php 
include('session.php');
print_r($_POST);
$ItemIDs = $_POST['itemid'];
$PriceSolds = $_POST['pricesold'];
$QtySolds = $_POST['amount'];
$Date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
$BranchIDs = $_POST['branchid'];
$EmployeeIDs = $_POST['employeeid'];
$MemberIDs = $_POST['memberid'];

$size = sizeof($ItemIDs);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO Receipt_seq VALUES (NULL);";
$db->query($sql2);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ){
 $ItemID = $ItemIDs[$i];
 $PriceSold = $PriceSolds[$i];
 $QtySold = $QtySolds[$i];
 $BranchID = $BranchIDs[$i];
 $EmployeeID = $EmployeeIDs[$i];
 $MemberID = $MemberIDs[$i];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO Receipt (ItemId,PriceSold,QtySold,RDate,BranchID,EmployeeID,MemberID) VALUES ('{$ItemID}', '{$PriceSold}', '{$QtySold}','{$Date}','$BranchID','$EmployeeID','$MemberID')";
 $db->query($sql);
}
?>
```

The Id for the receipt will be automatically generated using a trigger system. The only problem I have right now is that I can send in one row data just fine. But the moment I add a second row, it gives me an error **Undefine index ...**. I tried to use `print_r($_POST);` to see what is happening and this is the result. When I submitted one row of data it looked fine [one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWvB.png) But when I added the second row it gave me this error [more than one row error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8a6Z.png). I am a beginner at making website so I am not sure what I am doing is correct or not. Please help, thank you. I added and image of what my sales page will look like so you might have a better understanding of what I am trying to do [Sales page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVwW6.png).

Comment: What shows `print_r($_POST);` in case of more than one row? It can't retrieve data via defined indexes

Comment: the problem is when you use `item[][itemid]` it becomes multi leveled. meaning you should point out to `$_POST['item']` first, then collect the sub items inside

Comment: i'd suggest though to do the heavy lifting on the actual form markup itself, meaning `item[0][index1]` and `item[0][index2]` and so on, so that when the form is submitted, it's already formatted in row fashion, you'll only need to use `foreach` and go on in looping, sidenote: your insertion is vulnerable to sql injection though

Comment: @Kevin Can you give me an example of how to for each will be coded?

Comment: just add the index into the js code that you have,you already used `i` as your index, just concatenate it in `item[]`, try it, then submit it

Comment: @Kevin I have tried to add the index as you suggested. But it still has the same issue. The frst row is fine, but the moment I add the second row, it no longer works. When I use only the first row, this is what is inside the array.
Array ( [submit] => Submit [item] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [itemid] => [amount] => [pricesold] => [branchid] => [employeeid] => [memberid] => ) ) )
But when I use the second row it shows this.
Array ( [submit] => Submit )

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: take note, don't set your inputs as `disabled` as they will not be captured, just set them to `readonly` and they'll be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify points above, you **MUST** set the inputs with attribute `readonly` **NOT** `disabled` so that the previous input rows get included.

Then just follow what I said in the comments by adding (concatenating) the index into the dynamically added input rows:

```
$('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='item["+i+"][itemid]' 
                                      //    ^ add the dynamic index here
```

*Sidenote: Don't forget to wrap the table with the form tag*

I'll just add the important bits, so all in all:

a. Form tag before table tag

```
<div class="col-md-12 column">
    <form action="" method="post"> <!-- this  -->
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
```

b. change to `readonly` instead of `disabled` attribute and add the index in the "add row"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 1;
      $("#add_row").click(function() {
        $('#addr'+(i-1)).find('input').attr('readonly',true);

        $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='item["+i+"][itemid]'  placeholder='ItemID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][amount]' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][pricesold]' placeholder='PriceSold' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][branchid]' placeholder='BranchID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][employeeid]' placeholder='EmployeeID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][memberid]' placeholder='MemberID' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
  });
```

Full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 1;
      $("#add_row").click(function() {
        $('#addr'+(i-1)).find('input').attr('readonly',true);

        $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='item["+i+"][itemid]'  placeholder='ItemID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][amount]' placeholder='Amount' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][pricesold]' placeholder='PriceSold' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][branchid]' placeholder='BranchID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][employeeid]' placeholder='EmployeeID' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='text' name='item["+i+"][memberid]' placeholder='MemberID' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <form action="" method="post">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th class="text-center">
                                ItemID
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                Amount
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                Price Sold
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                Branch ID
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                EmployeeID
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                MemberID
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                            <tr id='addr0'>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[0][itemid]' placeholder='ItemID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[0][amount]' placeholder='Amount' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[0][pricesold]' placeholder='PriceSold' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[0][branchid]' placeholder='BranchID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[0][employeeid]' placeholder='EmployeeID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='item[0][memberid]' placeholder='MemberID' class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                            <input class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit"/>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="add_row" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" style="position: absolute; right: 130px;">New row</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done as you suggested. Now I have to alter the insert php to match the new code. Hope it works.

Comment: @PatcharagitStrauss the rest is straightforward, its your good ol' foreach

Comment: Yes, thank you again. Also, to make sure using the print_r. Is this normal? This is one row
Array ( [submit] => Submit [item] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [itemid] => [amount] => [pricesold] => [branchid] => [employeeid] => [memberid] => ) ) )
And this is two rows
Array ( [submit] => Submit [item] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [itemid] => [amount] => [pricesold] => [branchid] => [employeeid] => [memberid] => ) ) )
It looks exatcly the same?

Comment: @PatcharagitStrauss you probably have not applied the `<form>` tag to wrap the whole table yet

Comment: Oh, I did forget. Thank you.

Comment: can you help me with another problem that I posted? [dropdown list problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942988/how-to-add-dropdown-options-to-multi-row-form?noredirect=1#comment106011693_59942988) @Kevin